# Create 2 Cable with 700 Series Roomba

Tags: ros, irobot-create, roomba

For the last few months I have been playing with ROS on an nVidia Jetson TK1 development board. Up until this point, it has mostly been playing with the GPIO header, an Arduino Uno, a couple physical contact sensors, and a few custom motor and servo boards that I slapped together. But lately I've been eyeing an old 700 series Roomba that has been gathering dust (was replaced by an 800 series).

Does anyone know if the Communication Cable for Create 2 will work with a 700 series Roomba?

I know there are DIY designs out there, but I have always been a fan of using off-the-shelf components if they exist - you rarely save more money than your time is worth if it is something like a cable or similar component. So if the Create 2 cable will work, I'll use that. If not, I'll see what I can do to make my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will work! The electrical interface is the same between the Create 2 and the 700 series Roomba; however, the position of the mini-DIN is changed. Instead of being to the right, under the top cover, the connector can be found under a rubber gasket under the handle. As long as any Create cable can physically fit in that location (and the one iRobot sells can), it will work the same as it does on a Create.

<sup>Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.</sup>

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the mini-din. Have you had a chance to try it out, or heard of someone doing it?

Comment: Sounds great. I suspect it will fit with the right angle (will post here either way), but I have no problem ripping the handle off to get it out of the way. It's going to be covered by piece of PVC and some standoffs at some point anyway.

Comment: It will fit without any modifications to robot or cable. The serial communication works fine as well.

Comment: FYI, you can safely remove the handle on a 700 series Roomba without screws and without any damage to the robot.  You have to remove the faceplate, and the semicircular ring below the center section, then slide the handle back to remove.  they are all secured with plastic snaps.